# S-Unit equations in cyclotomic fields

Tags: number-theory

By a Siegel's result, one knows that there exist only finitely many solutions of the equation: $$x+y=1$$ where the unknowns $x$ and $y$ are units in the ring of integers of a cyclotomic field. Do you know an algorithm that can describe all the solutions?